# How to Create a Hash from Multiple Arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

I have a text file exported from Ansys which contains four columns (NodeNumber, Xcoordinate, Ycoordinate, and Zcoordinate).  I would like to take the contents of this text file and create a hash table in perl.  I am able to create an array for each value in the columns through a regular expression, but my question is how can I take these arrays and put them in a hash table?  I ultimately want a list of all the node numbers with condition where Ycoordinate == 0 and Zcoordinate == 0.

Here is my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Cwd;

use lib "C:/begperl";
use BeginPerlBioinfo;

open (MYINPUTFILE, "<xyzNodeCoords.lis");

my @XYZcoordData = <MYINPUTFILE>;
my @NodeNumber;
my @xCoord;
my @yCoord;
my @zCoord;


foreach (@XYZcoordData)
{
    if($_ =~ m/^\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/i)
    {
        push(@NodeNumber,$1);
        push(@xCoord,$2);
        push(@yCoord,$3);
        push(@zCoord,$4);
    }

}

exit(0);
```

How can I take four arrays above (@NodeNumber, @xCoord, @yCoord, @zCoord) and push them into a table?  The NodeNumber value is unique so it shall be used as a primary key.

Comment: You want a HoA? Seems like an AoH would make more sense.

Comment: Does AoH stand for Array of Hashes?  I just want a table or matrix to hold these values.  I am not sure what it is called in perl.  Nevertheless, what is syntax for pushing these tables into a Perl AoH?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "table" or a "matrix" in Perl, only arrays and hashes. My question stands; we have no idea what you want.

Comment: What do you want to do with your data after you stored it in your data structure? That is important to give you advice on what data structure to use and how to get it in.

Comment: What is the keys of the hash? How do you plan to access the hash?  If you don't know what the keys are, then you can't use a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I ultimately want a list of all the node numbers with condition where Ycoordinate == 0 and Zcoordinate == 0.*

```
my $qfn = 'xyzNodeCoords.lis';

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my @list;
while (<$fh>) {
   s/^\s+//;
   my ($node, $x, $y, $z) = split;
   push @list, $node if $y == 0 && $z == 0;
}
```